# struts 2 multiple file upload save path to database

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I have a huge form in which multiple documents of different types are being uploaded.
Doing the same in Struts 2 using the multiple file upload logic of struts.

```
private File[] upload;

private String[] uploadFileName;
```

These are the parameters of my class(action).
The name of the form fields have to be "upload" as per the class.

```
<s:file name="upload" type="file" id="file_photo"/>
<s:file name="upload" type="file" id="resume"/>
<s:file name="upload" type="file" id="result1"/>
<s:file name="upload" type="file" id="result2"/>
<s:file name="upload" type="file" id="result3"/>
```

(some fields may be optional to upload)
The files get uploaded correctly using copyFile. However within the upload[] array, how do I know which file belongs to which parameter as they bear the same name "upload", as I need to save the filename to database.

Please advise.

Comment: where can you get the filenames? should user give them or your system generate them?

Comment: you can use `uploadFileName` which is actual file name of the uploaded file (not the HTML name)

Comment: the user will upload the file, the application just stores the file at a proper location. However, the filename with path needs to be stored in database which is what i am not getting as the file name has to be same for all the file parameters.